# Problems with glew and gltools, _glewInit already defined

Tags: c++, glew, defined

I am trying to add shadders from opengl Superbible example to my program. The problem is, when I call any function from gltools i get

```
glew32.lib(glew32.dll) : error LNK2005: _glewInit already defined in gltools.lib(glew.obj)
```

After this i swapped glew32.lib with glew32s.lib. That resulted in an unhandled exception at

```
const M3DMatrix44f& GetMatrix(void) { return pStack[stackPointer]; }
```

The code I added

```
void Shadders::RenderScene()
{

    static CStopWatch rotTimer;

// Clear the window and the depth buffer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix(viewFrame);
    modelViewMatrix.Rotate(rotTimer.GetElapsedSeconds() * 10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    GLfloat vColor[] = { 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.f, 1.0f };

    glUseProgram(flatShader);
    glUniform4fv(locColor, 1, vColor);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(locMVP, 1, GL_FALSE, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix());  // The line that causes the unhandled exception
torusBatch.Draw();

modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();


glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

When i try to work aroud with

```
        GLfloat modmatrix[16], projmatrix[16];
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modmatrix);

    //M3DMatrix44f
    float MDWPRJMatrix[16];
    m3dMatrixMultiply44(MDWPRJMatrix, modmatrix, projmatrix);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(locMVP, 1, GL_FALSE, MDWPRJMatrix);
```

I get assertion failed with Expression:OPENGLUT_READY

I would like to know what causes this, and if possible, how to solve it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by linking glew32s.lib and adding `#define GLEW_STATIC` at the beginning of my code. Also, linked freeglut instead of openglut.